# Is it possible to implement automation for Oracle and DB2 with Jenkins and or Ansible?

Tags: oracle, db2

I'm curious if anyone has successfully used Jenkins and/or Ansible for automating routine tasks for Oracle and DB2 databases. From what I've looked up online options seem very limited. So far automation for these seem to amount to using a scheduler to run scripts or batch jobs. I'm trying to implement something more robust.

Comment: What kind of routine tasks?

Comment: I'll take anything I can get at this point. Gathering performance metrics, add/delete of users, granting privileges, etc. Right now I've seen Pentaho Kettle - Spoon being used and a Windows Task Scheduler on a VM. Its ok, it works, but this automation is still very manual. For Oracle all I've seen being used here is scripts.

Comment: Surely it's possible, but that's not what you're asking, right? So, _what_ are you asking?

Comment: Is it possible? I haven't found any Ansible modules for DB2 or Jenkins plugins. I have found some modules for Oracle but those were self-coded by someone and do not seem to be officially supported by Oracle. The first sentence I thought laid out clearly what I'm looking for, has anyone been successful in automating with Jenkins and/or Ansible. I'm assuming the how part of that yes/no answer would be included in the response.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for database vendor-supported Jenkins plugins and/or Ansible modules for Oracle and/or Db2.